# Upload files dynamically into different s3 buckets with django-storages boto3

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I'm using django-storages to upload into an s3 bucket.
But I want to be able to upload into a different s3 bucket than what I have set in my default in settings.py
My app has a different web page for each bucket and can access the contents.
Ideally I would want to pull the bucket name from the url and dynamically set the bucket name to where the file is being uploaded in my code.

```
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    if request.method == "POST":
        bucket = kwargs.get('bucket_name')
        form_model = Document()
        form_model.upload.storage = S3Boto3Storage(bucket=bucket)
        form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect("/bucket/"+bucket)
```

This only saves to the defaul location

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    if request.method == "POST":
        bucket = kwargs.get('bucket_name')
        form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.upload.storage = S3Boto3Storage(bucket=bucket)
            form.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect("/bucket/"+bucket)
```

Found my own answer